# Writing more compact version of my function

Tags: python

I would like to have the code below in more compact way ( one or two lines )

## foo.txt:

```
a:1
b:2
c:3
```

## code:

```
>>> r = {}
>>> for i in open('foo.txt','r').readlines():
...     k,v = i.split(':')
...     r[k]=v.strip()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
In [43]: with open("foo.txt") as fd:
    my_dict=dict(x.strip().split(":") for x in fd)
   ....:     

In [44]: my_dict
Out[44]: {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

another approach:

```
In [46]: with open("foo.txt") as fd:
    my_dict={k:v for k,v in (x.strip().split(':') for x in fd)}
   ....:     

In [47]: my_dict
Out[47]: {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

Comment: this will not strip the value from the left... For example this line: `a: 3`

Answer (score 1):

well if you only care about number of lines this will do

```
[r[i.split(':')[0]]=i.split(':')[1] for i in open('foo.txt','r').readlines()]
```

Comment: it is )) but that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open('input.txt', 'r') as csvfile:
    r = {row[0]: row[1] for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=":")}
```

Comment: I like it! nice way to do this

Answer (score 0):

That's really very compact already, and gains nothing from being written in less lines.

But if you really have to, here it is in one line:

```
r = dict(i.strip().split(':') for i in open('foo.txt','r').readlines())
```

I don't recommend it, your existing code is just fine.